# How to add Dynamically table row including text boxes and select box with Different Ids

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have developed a table. It has a facility to generate a table row dynamically when a button is pressed. But I am unable to add a select box when adding a new row. How can I do this? The HTML and JS codes are listed below.

```js
function addRow(tableID) {

  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var element1 = document.createElement("input");
  element1.type = "checkbox";
  element1.id = 'text' + rowCount + '';
  element1.name = "chkbox[]";
  cell1.appendChild(element1);

  //var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  //cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var element2 = document.createElement("input");
  element2.type = "text";
  element2.className = "form-control";
  element2.title = "Item-name";
  element2.id = 'item-name' + rowCount + '';
  element2.name = "item-name[]";
  cell2.appendChild(element2);

  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var element3 = document.createElement("input");
  element3.type = "text";
  element3.className = "form-control";
  element3.title = "Item-name";
  element3.id = 'qty' + rowCount + '';
  element3.name = "qty[]";
  cell3.appendChild(element3);

  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var element4 = document.createElement("input");
  element4.type = "text";
  element4.className = "form-control";
  element4.title = "Item-name";
  element4.id = 'unit-price-' + rowCount + '';
  element4.name = "unit-price[]";
  cell4.appendChild(element4);

  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  var element5 = document.createElement("input");
  element5.type = "text";
  element5.className = "form-control";
  element5.title = "Item-name";
  element5.id = 'toatal-' + rowCount + '';
  element5.name = "total-[]";
  cell5.appendChild(element5);
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      var row = table.rows[i];
      var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
      if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        if (rowCount <= 3) {
          alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
          break;
        }
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" style="background-color:white; text-align: center;" id="item-table">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td> </td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" id="btn-addrow" onclick="addRow('item-table')" class="btn-success form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow('item-table');" class="form-control btn-danger" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th style="text-align: center">Item Name</th>
    <th style="text-align: center">Quantity</th>
    <th style="text-align: center">unit Price</th>
    <th style="text-align: center">total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td class="col-md-4">
      <select name="selected_item[]" class="form-control">
                                                    <?php
                                                    include ('../svr/connection.php');
                                                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM User";
                                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                        echo '<option value=' . $row['user_name'] . '>' . $row['user_name'] . '</option>';
                                                    }
                                                    ?>   
                                                </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="it_re_qty[]" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="y" name="unit_price[]" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="it_re_qty" name="total[]" class="form-control col-md-1"></td>
    <!--<td> <input type="button"  value="Add Row" id="btn-addrow" onclick="addRow('item-table')" class="btn-success form-control"/></td>
                                            <td><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow('item-table');" class="form-control btn-danger" /></td>
                                        -->
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Try cloning in jQuery. It reduces code alot. Check this out. http://jsfiddle.net/Jaganathan/R2Her/

Comment: In JS code I don't see any dropdown element you have created. I see only 1 checkbox and 4 textboxes appended in your code. So there is no dropdown appending in new rows.

Answer (score 1):

> But I am unable to add a select box when adding a new row. How can I do this?

The select list can be cloned using [Node.cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode). And the original select list can be located with a selector using [Element.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector), like in the code below:

```
var selectList = table.rows[2].querySelector('select');
var element2 = selectList.cloneNode(true); //pass true for deep clone (to include options)
//set the id property
element2.id = 'selected-item'+rowCount;
cell2.appendChild(element2);
```

See a demonstration of this in the snippet below.

As others have mentioned, jQuery's [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method works similarly. Since jQuery was tagged in the original post, this could be used as well, using [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) to set the id attribute and [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo) to add the select list to a cell in the new table row:

```
var selectList = $('select.form-control');
var element2 = selectList.clone(); //performs deep clone by default
element2.attr('id','selected-item'+rowCount);
element2.appendTo(cell2);
```

```js
function addRow(tableID) {

  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var element1 = document.createElement("input");
  element1.type = "checkbox";
  element1.id = 'text' + rowCount + '';
  element1.name = "chkbox[]";
  cell1.appendChild(element1);

  //var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  //cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var selectList = table.rows[2].querySelector('select');
  /*var element2 = document.createElement("select");
  element2.className = "form-control";
  element2.id = 'item-name' + rowCount + '';
  element2.name = "selected_item[]";
  var existingOptions = table.rows[0].querySelector('option');
  existingOptions.each(function(option) {
  
      element2.appendchild(option.cloneNode(true));
  });*/
  var element2 = selectList.cloneNode(true);
  element2.id = 'selected-item'+rowCount;
  cell2.appendChild(element2);

  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var element3 = document.createElement("input");
  element3.type = "text";
  element3.className = "form-control";
  element3.title = "Item-name";
  element3.id = 'qty' + rowCount + '';
  element3.name = "qty[]";
  cell3.appendChild(element3);

  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var element4 = document.createElement("input");
  element4.type = "text";
  element4.className = "form-control";
  element4.title = "Item-name";
  element4.id = 'unit-price-' + rowCount + '';
  element4.name = "unit-price[]";
  cell4.appendChild(element4);

  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  var element5 = document.createElement("input");
  element5.type = "text";
  element5.className = "form-control";
  element5.title = "Item-name";
  element5.id = 'toatal-' + rowCount + '';
  element5.name = "total-[]";
  cell5.appendChild(element5);



}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      var row = table.rows[i];
      var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
      if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        if (rowCount <= 3) {
          alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
          break;
        }
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
      }


    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" style="background-color:white; text-align: center;" id="item-table">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td> </td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" id="btn-addrow" onclick="addRow('item-table');" class="btn-success form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow('item-table');" class="form-control btn-danger" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th style="text-align: center">Item Name</th>
    <th style="text-align: center">Quantity</th>
    <th style="text-align: center">unit Price</th>
    <th style="text-align: center">total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td class="col-md-4">
      <select name="selected_item[]" class="form-control">
            <option></option>  
            <option value="laurie">Laurie</option> 
            <option value="sam">Sam</option>  
       </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="it_re_qty[]" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="y" name="unit_price[]" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="it_re_qty" name="total[]" class="form-control col-md-1"></td>
    <!--<td> <input type="button"  value="Add Row" id="btn-addrow" onclick="addRow('item-table');idincrement;" class="btn-success form-control"/></td>
                                            <td><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow('item-table');" class="form-control btn-danger" /></td>
                                        -->
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but if you're talking about the 'Item Name' Column, try changing:
`var element2 = document.createElement("input");` 
to 
`var element2 = document.createElement("select");`